# Why is it "id est" instead of "illud est" if it often means "that is"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

If "i.e." or "id est" is often used to say "that is...", why do we use "id" instead of "illud"? Doesn't "id est" translate to "*it* is"?

Comment: *Doesn't "id est" translate to "it is"?* No it doesn't? Any useful Latin dictionary will translate *is, ea, id* as “he, she, it, this, that.” (But of course the real answer, as given below, is that we use *id* because the ancient Romans used *id*, and they used *id* because they couldn't know (and wouldn't have cared) what English speakers say.)

Answer (score 15):

Translation between two languages is rarely as easy as swapping each word for its equivalent in the other language. Function words in particular, for example demonstratives like *id* and *illud* (and *hoc*, *istud*, etc.), don't align perfectly between English and Latin. Both 'it' and 'that' are reasonable translations of *id*, depending on context.

And in this instance, we are dealing with fixed expressions. It so happens that in English, the idiomatic expression is *that is*, while in Latin it's *id est*. This is quite arbitrary. The French expression *c'est à dire* translates literally to 'that/it is to say', while the Swedish *det vill säga* would be 'it wants to say' in English. It's perfectly possible to conceive of a world where English and Latin ended up with other standardised phrases than the ones we are used to.

You may want to look up *is* and *ille* (the masculine of *id* and *illud*, respectively) in a dictionary. Here's Lewis and Short: [*is*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D76%3Aentry%3Dis), [*ille*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D5%3Aentry%3Dille).

Comment: @Alexa Not all translation is [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_translation) because idiom occurs in language which means that much language has meaning that is more-than-the-sum-of-the-parts.